# Why am I unable to load "Groceries" data set in R?

Tags: r, dataset, data-mining

I am unable to load *Groceries* data set in R.

Can anyone help?

```
> data()

Data sets in package ‘datasets’:

AirPassengers                Monthly Airline Passenger Numbers 1949-1960
BJsales                      Sales Data with Leading Indicator
BJsales.lead (BJsales)       Sales Data with Leading Indicator
BOD                          Biochemical Oxygen Demand
CO2                          Carbon Dioxide Uptake in Grass Plants
ChickWeight                  Weight versus age of chicks on different diets
DNase                        Elisa assay of DNase
EuStockMarkets               Daily Closing Prices of Major European Stock Indices,
                             1991-1998
Formaldehyde                 Determination of Formaldehyde
HairEyeColor                 Hair and Eye Color of Statistics Students
Harman23.cor                 Harman Example 2.3
Harman74.cor                 Harman Example 7.4
Indometh                     Pharmacokinetics of Indomethacin
InsectSprays                 Effectiveness of Insect Sprays
JohnsonJohnson               Quarterly Earnings per Johnson & Johnson Share
LakeHuron                    Level of Lake Huron 1875-1972
LifeCycleSavings             Intercountry Life-Cycle Savings Data
Loblolly                     Growth of Loblolly pine trees
Nile                         Flow of the River Nile
Orange                       Growth of Orange Trees
OrchardSprays                Potency of Orchard Sprays
PlantGrowth                  Results from an Experiment on Plant Growth
Puromycin                    Reaction Velocity of an Enzymatic Reaction
Seatbelts                    Road Casualties in Great Britain 1969-84
Theoph                       Pharmacokinetics of Theophylline
Titanic                      Survival of passengers on the Titanic
ToothGrowth                  The Effect of Vitamin C on Tooth Growth in Guinea Pigs
UCBAdmissions                Student Admissions at UC Berkeley
UKDriverDeaths               Road Casualties in Great Britain 1969-84
UKgas                        UK Quarterly Gas Consumption
USAccDeaths                  Accidental Deaths in the US 1973-1978
USArrests                    Violent Crime Rates by US State
USJudgeRatings               Lawyers' Ratings of State Judges in the US Superior Court
USPersonalExpenditure        Personal Expenditure Data
UScitiesD                    Distances Between European Cities and Between US Cities
VADeaths                     Death Rates in Virginia (1940)
WWWusage                     Internet Usage per Minute
WorldPhones                  The World's Telephones
ability.cov                  Ability and Intelligence Tests
airmiles                     Passenger Miles on Commercial US Airlines, 1937-1960
airquality                   New York Air Quality Measurements
anscombe                     Anscombe's Quartet of 'Identical' Simple Linear
                             Regressions
attenu                       The Joyner-Boore Attenuation Data
attitude                     The Chatterjee-Price Attitude Data
austres                      Quarterly Time Series of the Number of Australian
                             Residents
beaver1 (beavers)            Body Temperature Series of Two Beavers
beaver2 (beavers)            Body Temperature Series of Two Beavers
cars                         Speed and Stopping Distances of Cars
chickwts                     Chicken Weights by Feed Type
co2                          Mauna Loa Atmospheric CO2 Concentration
crimtab                      Student's 3000 Criminals Data
discoveries                  Yearly Numbers of Important Discoveries
esoph                        Smoking, Alcohol and (O)esophageal Cancer
euro                         Conversion Rates of Euro Currencies
euro.cross (euro)            Conversion Rates of Euro Currencies
eurodist                     Distances Between European Cities and Between US Cities
faithful                     Old Faithful Geyser Data
fdeaths (UKLungDeaths)       Monthly Deaths from Lung Diseases in the UK
freeny                       Freeny's Revenue Data
freeny.x (freeny)            Freeny's Revenue Data
freeny.y (freeny)            Freeny's Revenue Data
infert                       Infertility after Spontaneous and Induced Abortion
iris                         Edgar Anderson's Iris Data
iris3                        Edgar Anderson's Iris Data
islands                      Areas of the World's Major Landmasses
ldeaths (UKLungDeaths)       Monthly Deaths from Lung Diseases in the UK
lh                           Luteinizing Hormone in Blood Samples
longley                      Longley's Economic Regression Data
lynx                         Annual Canadian Lynx trappings 1821-1934
mdeaths (UKLungDeaths)       Monthly Deaths from Lung Diseases in the UK
morley                       Michelson Speed of Light Data
mtcars                       Motor Trend Car Road Tests
nhtemp                       Average Yearly Temperatures in New Haven
nottem                       Average Monthly Temperatures at Nottingham, 1920-1939
npk                          Classical N, P, K Factorial Experiment
occupationalStatus           Occupational Status of Fathers and their Sons
precip                       Annual Precipitation in US Cities
presidents                   Quarterly Approval Ratings of US Presidents
pressure                     Vapor Pressure of Mercury as a Function of Temperature
quakes                       Locations of Earthquakes off Fiji
randu                        Random Numbers from Congruential Generator RANDU
rivers                       Lengths of Major North American Rivers
rock                         Measurements on Petroleum Rock Samples
sleep                        Student's Sleep Data
stack.loss (stackloss)       Brownlee's Stack Loss Plant Data
stack.x (stackloss)          Brownlee's Stack Loss Plant Data
stackloss                    Brownlee's Stack Loss Plant Data
state.abb (state)            US State Facts and Figures
state.area (state)           US State Facts and Figures
state.center (state)         US State Facts and Figures
state.division (state)       US State Facts and Figures
state.name (state)           US State Facts and Figures
state.region (state)         US State Facts and Figures
state.x77 (state)            US State Facts and Figures
sunspot.month                Monthly Sunspot Data, from 1749 to "Present"
sunspot.year                 Yearly Sunspot Data, 1700-1988
sunspots                     Monthly Sunspot Numbers, 1749-1983
swiss                        Swiss Fertility and Socioeconomic Indicators (1888) Data
treering                     Yearly Treering Data, -6000-1979
trees                        Diameter, Height and Volume for Black Cherry Trees
uspop                        Populations Recorded by the US Census
volcano                      Topographic Information on Auckland's Maunga Whau Volcano
warpbreaks                   The Number of Breaks in Yarn during Weaving
women                        Average Heights and Weights for American Women


Use ‘data(package = .packages(all.available = TRUE))’
to list the data sets in all *available* packages.

> head(Groceries)
Error in head(Groceries) : object 'Groceries' not found
> groceries <- data(Groceries)
Warning message:
In data(Groceries) : data set ‘Groceries’ not found
> library(datasets)
> groceries <- data(Groceries)
Warning message:
In data(Groceries) : data set ‘Groceries’ not found
>
```

Comment: `Groceries` doesn't seem to appear in `datasets` -- it's not in the list you show??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groceries is in the arules package.

```
install.packages("arules")
library(arules)
data(Groceries)
```